# Eclipse Maven not showing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, m2eclipse

For some reason I am unable to see the all other spring jars when I try to look for dependencies.
I tried deleting the org.springframework from the m2 local repository.
tried to update / rebuild local and global indexes.
but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Try clicking on the arrow to the left of org.springgramework what does what display?

Comment: 4.1.4RELEASE[pom.lastUpdated]  did try to delete it from m2 repository

Comment: Well, if you deleted the spring jars from the local repository and rebuilt the index shouldn't the results *be empty*?

Comment: @Nicholas  I tried to update the project it keeps on downloading the 4.1.4RELEASE[pom.lastUpdated]  jar inside the local repository

Comment: Well, just put in the version you want. Eclipse won't show you what's available from global repositories, only what you have previously downloaded into your local repository.

Comment: @Nicholas isn't the maven plugin suppose to show me the jars available in global repository (correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: No. There is too many there. That's like downloading the entire internet. You need to go to the repository and search for the jar you want and look and see what versions are there, or go to the vendor and see what versions they describe.

Comment: In Eclipse you can configure to download an repository index during startup which is useful in particular in those situations. It will show all available artifacts and not only those which have been downloaded...See Preferences->Maven...Apart from that the whole question is related to M2E and **not** maven...

Answer (score -1):

You might have kept the Maven on "Offline" mode.

Go to eclipse (or spring sts) preferences --> type "maven" in search box --> click on "Maven" item in the list on left side -->

1. Make sure **"Offline"** and **"Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories"** check boxes are **unchecked**
2. Also make sure **"Download repository index updates on startup"** is **checked**.

Restart eclipse. Wait for eclipse to update indexes. This should solve your problem.